# php mysql bulk or batch update multiple columns and multiple rows but not if column is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have this case style update. This example only updates 3 rows, but in real app it could be hundreds or thousands of records at a time.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET 
col_1 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '43333' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '43334'
WHEN 555557 THEN '43335'
END, 
col_2 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '893' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '893'
WHEN 555557 THEN '893'
END, 
col_3 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '2016-06-09 06:03:00' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '2016-06-09 06:04:00'
WHEN 555557 THEN '2016-06-09 06:05:00'
END, 
col_4 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '37064896499' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '37064896500'
WHEN 555557 THEN '37064896501'
END, 
col_5 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '93270106785000243103' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '93270106785000243104'
WHEN 555557 THEN '93270106785000243105'
END, 
col_6 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN now() 
WHEN 555556 THEN now()
WHEN 555557 THEN now()
END, 
col_7 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '93' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '94'
WHEN 555557 THEN '95'
END, 
col_8 = CASE id 
WHEN 555555 THEN '270' 
WHEN 555556 THEN '271'
WHEN 555557 THEN '272'
END 
WHERE id IN (555555,555556,555557)
```

I want to know if it's possible to manipulate this so it doesn't write data to the columns in every case and record if the column has data already (and if it's a date column then don't update the date if it's something other than 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Do I have to edit each WHEN line or once at the end where it says WHERE id IN (555555)?

The php script builds all the cases then at the end it bulk updates all the records in one query.

Anyway, how about this (which is better for what i'm trying to accomplish).....do not update any of the 8 columns if only 1 of the columns has data, for example if col_1 has data?

Update

this is what i have after one of the suggestions, but still not working. only trying it on col_1 until i get it right, then i'll do 2 through 8.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET 
col_1 = CASE col_1 WHEN col_1<>'' THEN
    CASE id 
        ".$col_1_loop."
    END
ELSE col_9 = CASE col_9 WHEN col_9<>'' THEN
    CASE id 
        ".$col_1_loop."
    END
END,
col_2 = CASE id
    ".$col_2_loop."
END,
col_3 = CASE id
    ".$col_3_loop."
END,
col_4 = CASE id
    ".$col_4_loop."
END,
col_5 = CASE id
    ".$col_5_loop."
END,
col_6 = CASE id
    ".$col_6_loop."
END,
col_7 = CASE id
    ".$col_7_loop."
END,
col_8 = CASE id
    ".$col_8_loop."
END
WHERE id IN (".$id_loop.")
```

if col_1 not empty put data in col_9, 
col_2 goes to col_10 if col_2 is not empty, 
col_3 goes to col_11 if col_3 doesn't have zero date and time, 
col_4 goes to col_12 if col_4 is not empty, 
col_5 goes to col_13 if col_5 is not empty, 
col_6 goes to col_14 if col_6 doesn't have zero date and time, 
col_7 goes to col_15 if col_7 is not empty, 
col_8 goes to col_16 if col_8 is not empty

Comment: These values, where did you get? Maybe you could use a different approach to your update, using update from select, join, ...

Comment: This query is absolute murder to parse, maintain, and understand. Why not do N queries for N updates, an update should take no more than a fraction of a millisecond anyway, or if you really have thousands of rows, create a temporary table and do an `UPDATE` joined against it. For the sake of your own sanity and that of others, **do not do this**.

Comment: well we are ok with 200 milliseconds (0.2 seconds) per 10,000 records. just wish i didn't have to do a precheck on the table for what's filled, because then it's like over 10 minutes per 10,000 rows. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add you condition for not update in where clause eg:

```
UPDATE table_name 
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE id 
    WHEN 555555 THEN '43333' 
    WHEN 555556 THEN '43334'
    WHEN 555557 THEN '43335'
    END, 
    col_2 = CASE id 
    WHEN 555555 THEN '893' 
    WHEN 555556 THEN '893'
    WHEN 555557 THEN '893'
    END, 
    ......
    .....
    col_8 = CASE id 
    WHEN 555555 THEN '270' 
    WHEN 555556 THEN '271'
    WHEN 555557 THEN '272'
    END 
    WHERE id IN (555555,555556,555557)
    AND (col_1 is not null or col_2 is not null ........ or col_8 is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also a nested CASE

```
    UPDATE table_name 
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE col_1 WHEN col1 is null THEN
                            CASE id 
                            WHEN 555555 THEN '43333' 
                            WHEN 555556 THEN '43334'
                            WHEN 555557 THEN '43335'
                            END
                        ELSE col_1
                        END, 
    ......
    ......
    col_9 = CASE col_1 WHEN col1 is null THEN
                            CASE id 
                            WHEN 555555 THEN '43333' 
                            WHEN 555556 THEN '43334'
                            WHEN 555557 THEN '43335'
                            END
                        ELSE  'YOUR_DATA_FOR_COL9'
                        END, 

    WHERE id IN (555555,555556,555557)
```

Comment: can you help me with this nested case? how do i write the ELSE if i want it to put data in col_9 if col_1 has data. look at updated question. also don't you mean not null? but null or not null didn't work, so i'll show you what i used there. also don't you have to repeat the column name right before is null?